# How to represent inheritance/overrides in Azure ARM template parameters?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

What is a good solution to represent inheritance/overrides in Azure ARM template parameters? Is there something like:

UnitedStates.json:

```
{
  ...
  "parameters": {
    "keyVaultName": { "value": "keyvaultus" }
  }
}
```

WestUS.json:

```
{
  ...
  "base": "UnitedStates.json"
  "parameters": {
    "keyVaultName": { "value": "@@inherit" }
    "webAppName": { "value": "westus-demoapp" }
}
```

Comment: It would help to understand the scenario a bit better and what you're trying to accomplish...  One way to override params would be using a defaultValue in the declaration and then override with a parameter during deployment (depends on how you deploy, to state how you would do that).

Answer (score 1):

> What is a good solution to represent inheritance/overrides in Azure ARM template parameters?

I don't know why you need to inheritance/overrides in Azure ARM template parameters. Based on my experience, if you want to deploy azure resource according different condition, now azure resource template support [conditionally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/building-blocks/extending-templates/conditional-deploy) deploy a resource. You could implement in the arm template.

Another way to do that is you could use the custom script to control the logic.  For example, you could create mutiple parameters json files. Then you could use your logical code to control which parameter json file should be used.

Powershell demo code:

```
if($localtion -eq "WestUS")
{
    $deployParameterFile = D:\Azure\Templates\WestUS.json
}
if($localtion -eq "UnitedStates")
{
    $deployParameterFile = D:\Azure\Templates\UnitedStates.json
}
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx" -TemplateFile "D:\Azure\Templates\deploy.json" -TemplateParameterFile $deployParameterFile
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way of achieving that natively. You can write powershell\whatever scripts that would kinda achieve that by parsing base json parameters and editing those into the nested parameters file. Cant think of any other way of doing this.